# how to succesfully represent a good hand

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-strategy, psychology

in a recent cash game i tried to represent a higher hand in order to get my opponent to fold. the game played out like this:

http://www.boomplayer.com/en/poker-hands/Boom/21219508_CE475D85C2

after a 3-bet pre-flop, i check-raised out of position to represent a queen or some middle pocket pair, maybe even ace. i then tried to slowplay it hoping to check-raise or even check-shove on the river and get the villain to fold. however, the villain simply checked and i lost at showdown.

should i have played the flop and turn differently to get my opponent to fold without potentially losing tons of chips? what are the general strategies and tips for over-representing your hand?

Answer (score 2):

Not that way.

The cut off is not a good position to bluff in. That was a 2 bet pre-flop - one raise.

On the flop you have to put AQ in his range.  He called a raise pre-flop.

Check raise the flop is a show of strength but it is also expensive. It was a small re-raise - you were giving him 4:1 - he bet out he is not going to fold to a small re-raise like that.

You could have just bet out 7 for the same effect. Your bluffs are now more expensive on every street.  Then follow up on the turn with like 12.

You got called on the flop. You both checked the turn. Why did you check the river?  Any hand that will fold to a raise is going to check there.

Comment: With 20/20 hindsight, the only way the OP is taking this pot is to bet the turn, and maybe big bet on river. I think the key thing here that Paparazzi said is that the cutoff is not a good position to bluff in. The OP should find a chalkboard and write that one hundred times.